# Qemu restart when I reload the segment registers with Rust inline assembly

Tags: assembly, rust, x86-64, qemu, osdev

I'm currently writing a kernel and I have troubles understanding how to load the GDT. In particular, I tried the following code, but the kernel reboot when it hit an `mov R, ax` instruction with R any of the segment registers present below, or when it hit the `retf` instruction. At this point, my kernel run in protected mode on the x86_64 architecture.

Do you have any idea why ? I have the same segments as here : https://wiki.osdev.org/GDT_Tutorial (my TSS segment is empty, but I don't think that this is the problem)

```rust
#[repr(C, packed)]
pub struct Gdt {
    offset: u64,
    /// this is the size in bytes, - 1
    size: u16,
}

impl Gdt {
    pub unsafe fn load(&'static self) {
        unsafe {
            asm!(
                r#"
                lgdt [{self}]
                mov ax, 0x10
                mov ds, ax
                mov es, ax
                mov fs, ax
                mov gs, ax
                mov ss, ax
                mov rax, [rip + 2f]
                push 0x8
                push rax
                retf
            2:
                nop
            "#,
            self = in(reg) self,
            );
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to change the order of the instructions or to remove some of them to see what it does, but the kernel keep rebooting on. I also tried to see what the problem was by launching qemu with `-d cpu_reset` and it reboot because of a triple fault.

Comment: *At this point, my kernel runs in **protected mode** on the x86_64 architecture.*. Protected mode is 32-bit mode (or 16-bit) and it can't run 64-bit code in a way you'd expect. You will need to enter 64-bit mode to run 64-bit code.

Comment: As for why it goes wrong here, in 32-bit protected mode, the encoding that would mean `[rip + rel32]` actually means `[disp32]`.  But if it crashes before the `mov rax, [rip + 2f]`, that would be something else, like a difference in GDT format.  A good debugger that knows what mode the CPU is in and can disassemble accordingly should show you, e.g. the one built-in to Bochs.  Any half-decent debugger should also be able to show you what the first fault was that led to a double and then triple fault; that's a bare minimum for usability.

Comment: I was told that I have to enter long mode after setting up the gdt and the idt.

Comment: You need a minimal 32-bit GDT to reload segment regs in protected mode, and that has to be done with 32-bit code.  https://wiki.osdev.org/Global_Descriptor_Table#Long_Mode_System_Segment_Descriptor shows the 2 different formats (with different sizes for each entry)

Comment: Oh, I thought that I could directly load a 64-bit GDT. I'll try that.

Comment: When you eventually do have to write a 64-bit version  - You probably wanted to do `lea rax, [rip+2f]` instead of `mov rax, [rip+2f]`. You would also have to use `retfq` and not `retf`. Your code also clobbers `rax` without actually telling the Rust compiler.